# Jar not running on Unix Server

Tags: java

I am running the jar on unix server and getting the following exception. It was working earlier

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.log4j.Logger              
                    at bo.ExecuteScheduler.<clinit>(ExecuteScheduler.java:25)
                    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
                    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:200)
                    at java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method)
                    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:172)
                    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:56)
            Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Logger
                    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:423)
                    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:660)
                    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:626)
                    ... 6 more
```

Comment: Something changed..or the place of the jar, or the libraries relation?

Comment: You're missing a one or more dependent libraries, namely log4j in this case

Comment: Earlier it was working fine. Something has changed, how to find that.

Comment: If you have the backup of that jar(previously working)  and then you do compare the lib folder in two jars. But anyway log4j jar is missing that's the  issue

Comment: Are you sure you're running it as java -jar? Sometimes if you don't, that's the error you receive

Comment: yes, I am running it with Java -jar and there are other jars on the same server which are also not running. Please help.........

Comment: did you recently delete the Log4J jar?

Comment: No, I haven't deleted anything. I have found that the same jar is running with the root user but not by any other user. Please help